# program in c runs into infinite loop when I use free()

Tags: c, malloc, free

I was trying out a linked list program in c where I use malloc() to allocate memory dynamically and then when I tried using free() at the end of the function, the program runs into an infinite loop.

Why is this happening ?

```
void Insert(int x, int pos)
{
    struct Node *newnode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    struct Node* temp, *left, *right;
    int i = 1;
    temp = head;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else{
        while(i != pos - 1)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        newnode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
    free(newnode);
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Are you sure it runs into an infinite loop because of free? That is pretty weird...

Comment: why do you free there, at all? Don;t you wanna use 'em later?

Comment: yes it runs into infinite loop, and i m not able to figure out why!

Comment: no, i just want to use it in this function

Comment: Sourav Ghosh is right, this is the not the right place to use `free()`, you free the node you just inserted.

Comment: ohh.. then where should i be using free() then?? And should i use free() at all??

Comment: With what value of pos did you call the insert?

Comment: The only was I see a (de-facto) infinite loop here is, when you call the function with pos <= 1 and the linked list is circular. Do not free the node before you remove it from the list.

Comment: You should use `free()` when you want to delete your node.

Comment: ok!! Thanks a lot @Silveris . I am using it in the wrong place!

Comment: If you've read on some site that you must free() memory in the same function as it is allocated, please delete the link from your history/favourites and try to forget you ever opened it :)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem: but using the global variable `head` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @she_be_me You're welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) in the wrong place, resulting in deleting the newly inserted node in your list.

> Should I use free() at all?

Yes, since you are using [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). The memory you allocated dynamically should be de-allocated by you, otherwise memory leaks shall happen.

> then where should I be using free() then?

In the place of your code that you do not need your list anymore. For example, at the end of your `main()`.

---

Unrelated, but by looking at your `insert()`, I can see that `head` is a global variable, which should be avoided, when able. Passing it as a parameter to your list functions, and making this variable non global is a better approach. If you want, take a look in this [list's](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/) code, which is fully commented and was the one I used to learn.

---

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!